# (Number and Number) in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have some VB script in classic ASP that looks like this:

```
if (x and y) > 0 then
    'do something
end if
```

It seems to work like this:
     (46 and 1) = 0
and
     (47 and 1) = 1

I don't understand how that works. Can someone explain that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [Bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

```
    47 is 101111
AND  1 is 000001
        = 000001
```

while

```
    46 is 101110
AND  1 is 000001
        = 000000
```

Answer (score 2):

It's doing a bitwise comparison -

> Bitwise operations evaluate two integral values in binary (base 2)
>   form. They compare the bits at corresponding positions and then assign
>   values based on the comparison.

and a further example -

```
x = 3 And 5
```

> The preceding example sets the value of x to 1. This happens for the
>   following reasons:
>
> The values are treated as binary:
>
> 3 in binary form = 011
>
> 5 in binary form = 101
>
> The And operator compares the binary representations, one binary
>   position (bit) at a time. If both bits at a given position are 1, then
>   a 1 is placed in that position in the result. If either bit is 0, then
>   a 0 is placed in that position in the result. In the preceding example
>   this works out as follows:
>
> 011 (3 in binary form)
>
> 101 (5 in binary form)
>
> 001 (The result, in binary form)
>
> The result is treated as decimal. The value 001 is the binary
>   representation of 1, so x = 1.

From - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
x = 47
y = -1

if (x AND y) > 0 then
    'erroneously passes condition instead of failing
end if
```

Code should be

```
if (x > 0) AND (y > 0) then
    'do something
end if
```

and then it'll work as expected.