# What is calculated between two numbers using the AND operator in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

```
Option explicit
Dim VarA
Dim VarB
VarA = 2560 and 3
VarB = 2560 and 4
wscript.echo "VarA is "&VarA
wscript.echo "VarB is "&VarB
```

Display

```
VarA is 0
VarB is 0
```

Somebody please explain how `VarA` and `VarB` are resulting `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s doing exactly what you asked it to.

From [the documentation for the `And` Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/e8zy95hw(v=vs.84)):

> If, and only if, both expressions evaluate to **True**, result is **True**. If either expression evaluates to **False**, result is **False**. The logical operation is not short-circuited. All expressions are evaluated.

In this instance though as [@MCND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304208/what-is-calculated-between-two-numbers-using-the-and-operator-in-vbscript/62304949?noredirect=1#comment110194863_62304949) again from the documentation:

> The `And` operator also performs a *bitwise* comparison of identically positioned bits in two numeric expressions and sets the corresponding bit in *result*.

Hence the `0` result instead of an explicit boolean value.

However, if you wanted to add the values together you needed to use the [Addition `+` Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/kd1e4aey%28v%3dvs.84%29).

> Sums two numbers.

```
Option Explicit
Dim VarA
Dim VarB
VarA = 2560 + 3
VarB = 2560 + 4
WScript.Echo "VarA is " & VarA
WScript.Echo "VarB is " & VarB
```

Output:

```
VarA is 2563
VarB is 2564
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [(Number and Number) in VBscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7766375/692942)
- [What is the difference between VBScript's + and & operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209159/692942)

Comment: The `And` operator also *"performs bitwise comparison of identically positioned bits in two numeric expressions"*, the reason OP gets a `0` in the variables.

Comment: @MCND Absolutely true, have amended the answer. Thank you.